# How do I use the Javascript String.replace() method correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML markup with some dummy text:

```
<p style="padding: 3%; border:1px solid black" id="myspan" ng-model="myspan" ng-mouseup="showSelectedText()">
    And so our resident genius, our Dr. Jekyll, explosively completed his transformation into Mr. Hyde.
    He declared this in front of the product design team, developers, management, and pre-launch customers. One of our project sponsors had the temerity to ask when the problem crippling our product would be fixed.
    Genius is a fickle beast. Sometimes you have the good fortune to work with a mad genius. Other times you are doomed to work with pure madness. There are also times when it is hard to tell the difference.
    This story is about the fall from grace of an extremely gifted team member with a deep understanding of our product’s architecture. He had an uncanny ability to forecast future requirements, and a ton of domain-specific knowledge.
    He was our top contributor. He was killing our flagship project.
</p>

    <input type="text" id="myword" value="{$ item $}">
    <input type ="button" value = "Highlight" ng-click="highlight($index, item)">
```

The Javascript code is:

```
    $scope.highlight = function(index, sentword) {
    var text = document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML;
    if (sentword != '') {
            word = sentword;  // must be in brackets
            var re = new RegExp(word, "gi"); // ignore case, global change
            document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = text.replace(sentword, "<mark>"+sentword+"</mark>" );
        }
    };
```

What this is supposed to do is to highlight a sent word to the Javascript function. This typically works as intended with short sentences, for example the following text: 
`And so our resident genius, our Dr. Jekyll, explosively completed his transformation into Mr. Hyde.` Correctly gets appended with `<mark>` tags however, the same sentence with an extra space at the end of the full stop: `And so our resident genius, our Dr. Jekyll, explosively completed his transformation into Mr. Hyde. *space*` does not correctly get appended with `<mark>` tags.

This is something I do not understand, because shorter sentences get replaced correctly, but long sentences that are sent to the Javascript function don't get replaced.

Comment: Could you  print the strings in your console and run the commands there to see if its working? I tried some examples in the console and it's working fine.

Comment: Here is a plunkr demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/NhB1m0MGnDOHifXM2blH?p=preview If you highlight the first 4 words and press highlight, it will highlight that string. However if you try to highlight a 20 word string or more and press highlight it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the trailing whitespace. The RegExp generated for both cases are different:

```js
var a = RegExp("Hello World", "gi");
var b = RegExp("Hello World ", "gi"); //look trailing whitespace

String(a) == String(b) //false
```

You have to use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) for cleaning the whitespaces.

```
var a = RegExp("Hello World", "gi");
var b = RegExp("Hello World ".trim(), "gi"); //look trailing whitespace

String(a) == String(b) //true
```

**Update 1**

Consider two thinks:

- Newline character is not matched. Try removing them from the text or implement more logic in your `highlight` function
- Previous highlighted text is not matched. Check regex generated vs innerHtml. Maybe you want to remove the `mark` tag before highlight the text.

Comment: That doesn't seem to quite work. Here is a plunkr demo: [link](plnkr.co/edit/NhB1m0MGnDOHifXM2blH?p=preview) If you highlight the first 4 words and press highlight, it will highlight that string. However if you try to highlight a 20 word string or more and press highlight it won't work.

Comment: check my update and let me know if you have some problems fixing the highlight function